# Linux, C, socket: how to specify TCP client port with structure sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, port

I am trying to create Linux tool with multiple TCP connections, which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 so I choose to use "sockaddr_storage".

Now, my question is, how do I bind client side socket to a specified (or random) TCP port?

For TCP client side, in one thread, if I just create 10 sockets and then connect() to server, then those 10 sockets will use sequential TCP ports in client side, for example, starting from 54594, then 54596, 54600, 54602, etc.

Now, I would like to bind those client sockets to different (randomized) TCP ports, how do I do with sockaddr_storage?

Thanks!

=============adding code ============

```
struct sockaddr_storage local_addr; 

sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)    

(*(struct sockaddr_in*)&local_addr).sin_port = 0;
local_addr_size = sizeof(local_addr);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addr, local_addr_size);

............
connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)
```

Comment: Your code is lacking all error checking. Without it, debugging is just a guessing game. Any system call that returns -1 should cause you to call `perror()` or friends and also not to continue as though it had succeeded.

Comment: That is just prototype code. But anyway, thanks for your suggestion to check the error code.

Comment: Don't kid yourself. You only put the error checking in after you've debugged it? You need the error messages *now.* That's why you've had to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to bind those client sockets to different (randomized) TCP ports

That happens automatically when you call `connect()` without calling `bind()` first. You don't need to write any code for this, and `sockaddr_storage` therefore doesn't come into it at all.

Comment: Thanks - I did that before but looks does not work. I just pasted my code, can you help me check it again?

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. Yes, your solution works:) I made the change but I did not "make install" of my new bits, so when run from cmd line, it runs previous installed version, not my changed version.